# App badge reappear when reinstalling the app on springboard iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am displaying application badge on my app. But when I reinstall the app icon shows last saved value on springboard. How do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I read here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html that if you have the app uninstalled for more than a day it will prompt for notifications again. Have you uninstalled and then waited a day (or pushed the clock a day in advance and restarted) and re-installed? It may also reset your badges.

Comment: I am not using Push Notification/Local Notification. I'm using application badge value but when I reinstall the app it shows badge with last settled value